# Transform.find not working? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Screenshot of hirearchy and full code
[image]

I am trying to reset the text of an input field when my function is called. I have done some debugging and now know that this line is the source of the issue:

```
Input.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text = "";
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: The input feild text is not affected.

Comment: A screenshot of the Text's Hierarchy and Inspector tab would be helpful.  Also, show where Input is declared and which function you are calling the code from.

Comment: How do you post screenshots after taking them?

Comment: Paste the screenshot in any image editor (e.g. painter), save the image, upload it using add image button in stackoverflow editor. BTW. it is better to reference your `Text` game object directly in design time, rather than finding it in run time if that is possible.

Comment: When people ask you for a code, you post the code not the screenshot. I only ask for screenshot of the Editor stuff not not for a code. By the way, you do understand that `Input.transform.Find ("Text").GetComponent<Text> ().text = "";` will change the text to an empty text? Is that what's happening? If not, can you use `Debug.Log` to see if your `Process` function is being called?

Comment: will be better to declare as public variable so include `using UnityEngine.UI;` and then declare the variable publicly accessible via insector window `public Text myText;` then when you want to change the text `myText.text = "";` but don't forget to apply the Text object to the inspector, (Drag and Drop it)

Comment: @Programmer Yes I am trying to change it to an empty text.

Comment: I seems to be working now even though I didn't change any code. I must have made a simple error. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do possibly do here is this

use [GetChild](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html) for getting the component of your Text

For example you put this code script in Input Heirarchy

```
GameObject text = null;
text = Transform.getchild(1).gameObject;
text.GetComponent<Text>();
```

Sorry I'm on phone so it's a lil bit messy

Answer (score 0):

Text object belonging to an InputField component should not be changed directly. Always use InputField.text instead, otherwise your InputField will override the text anyways.

Also, please post your code as code so we can modify it (or just check what it does without re-typing it), I can see at least a few things that can be improved. If you already specify public fields for your objects, why not

```
public InputField inputField;
```

instead of

```
public GameObject Input;
```

If you already have a reference, why do Find at all? (Having to use Find is a pretty bad sign already). If you make a I change I suggested you can change

```
Input.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text="";
```

into

```
inputField.text="";
```

which is what I believe you are trying to do here. On a side note, while not obligatory, its a good custom to write member fields lowercase, with uppercase classnames, Input.something looks like a static call to an Input class which is sligtly confusing, considering its a member in your case.

AdjustObInput is already a gameobject so you don't need to place ".gameObject" after it - it does nothing, gameObject.gameObject.gameObject it just referencing the same thing in a longer and slightly slower form